# Object Oriented Design in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I have been working in NodeJS for sometime now and cannot get around the concept of object oriented design in it. The best I have been able to do is:

```
var SomeClass = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.connect = function(){
        // function code
    }
    // for events/callbacks raised in this class
    ...(someVar, self.onDataReceived)
    self.onDataReceived = function(data){
        // do something with data
    }
}
```

This works well for self contained code but when classes have to interact with eachother, my code organization just goes out of the window.

So, my question is:

1. Is it really possible to have that good an application design in Javascript, the one we find in Rails/Laravel and love ?
2. If single threaded is the future, aren't there any better alternatives to NodeJS that facilitate code organization ?

Comment: The last question is not suited for SO, as it only attracts opinions. Unless someone answers with a study, but I don't think that'll happen. You better remove it from your post.

Comment: Maybe your "class interaction design" is messed up, not your class code? How do they interact with each other?

Comment: This might put some lights on https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-two-pillars-of-javascript-ee6f3281e7f3

Comment: IMO, in general, JS is usually better thought of as a scheme/functional language than a OO language. Due to that, how you approach designing the software differs, and the fundamental premise of this question is kind of broken

Comment: _"This works well for self contained code but when classes have to interact with eachother, my code organization just goes out of the window."_ For example...?

Answer (score -1):

Node.js is not a way to organize your code and, as for now, javascript does not provide a strong OOP natively (with ensured interfaces, easy inheritance, dependency-injection, ...).

However, it exists a [lots of libraries or frameworks](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=oop) helping you to do some OOP. I can suggest you the framework [Danf](https://github.com/gnodi/danf) which is an OOP framework providing a strong way to organize your code.